I'm looking for an obscure Buddhist text, I think it's Vajryana?
Let me paraphrase it as best I can.
There was a youth named Shining Countenance who approached the Tathagata. He prostrated to him and circumambulated him 7 times.
"My Lord I am going on a journey and I fear for my safety."
The blessed one spoke.
"There is a Buddha realm called "Shaking All Defilements." In that realm exists a Tathagata, an Arahant a fully enlightened Buddha named "Buddha Subsequent Conduct." Remember this Buddha, prostrate to him, pray to him and you will have no fear on your journey and your goals will be met."
